# What are some good practices for managing free functions in a C++ project?

Tags: c++

I'm writing some code to implement SIFT feature detector and there are some free functions that are used throughout the project e.g.

```
int iAlignUp( int a, int b ){return (a%b != 0) ? (a + b - a%b) : (a);}
int iDivUp( int a, int b ){return (a%b != 0) ? (a/b + 1) : (a/b);}
```

Should I encapsulate these functions in an unnamed namespace? I wish to manage my code so I can later scale it up without any problems.

Comment: This seems to be an opinionated question (asking for the best or even a preference). Those are off topic here.

Comment: Code review would be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks @CarlNorum, Now i'm aware of another valuable resource :)

Comment: What to you mean by 'free functions'?  'free' is a reserved word associated with 'malloc', right?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I meant function that are not part of any class, just general purpose functions that are used around in the poject

Comment: If lijal rewrote this as "What are some good practices ..." or "What are the different ways to ... ", could the mods reopen this question?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options depending on whether they are used in a single file or in multiple files.

**Put them in an unnamed namespace.**

If the functions are used only within a single source code file, you can put them in an unnamed namespace within that file.

```
namespace
{
    int iAlignUp( int a, int b ){return (a%b != 0) ? (a + b - a%b) : a;}
    int iDivUp( int a, int b ){return (a%b != 0) ? (a/b + 1) : (a/b);}
}
```

**Put them in a header file and an internal namespace.**

If the functions are used in multiple source code files, but not outside your project, you can put them in a header file included only within your project, and put them in an internal namespace.

```
namespace project
{
namespace impl
{
    inline int iAlignUp( int a, int b ){return (a%b != 0) ? (a + b - a%b) : a;}
    inline int iDivUp( int a, int b ){return (a%b != 0) ? (a/b + 1) : (a/b);}
}
}
```

In this example, the `project::impl` namespace is not visible outside the project. It is not mentioned in any externally accessible header files.

Comment: shouldn't the functions be declared `inline` when they are in a common header and used by multiple translation units?